# run SSH command and exit from WinSCP without interrupting the command

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, winscp

How to execute a command with SSH in WinSCP and exit without  interrupting the command ?

I just do not want to wait for command to end, because it take to many hours. And after i will execute the command i want to close the winscp but the command to be running on server. Is this possible, how to do this ?

Comment: i assume you run the command/script on linux, if so you can use `screen` to execute your command and log out. Have a look at this blog: http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a `screen` session.

In general to obtain such a behavior you should call a remote command like this:

```
ssh root@remoteserver screen -d -m ./somescript
```

I don't know if it's implemented in WinSCP options but for sure you can fire a custom command.

Comment: You can just run `screen ...` directly from WinSCP (Console window or Command Line panel)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl So when i tried using `screen` as a replacement for using background process'&'(http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10060), i got a message **"Must be connected to a terminal"**. Are u sure `screen` is supported in winscp command line automation?

Comment: Okay...i got it...its working fine with `-d -m` options which i missed earlier